# How to detect whether a player drops below a certain Y level

Tags: bukkit

I'm trying to write bukkit plugin and one of the features I would like to add is when a player drops to Y level 8 or lower it runs a command on that player. My current case is I'd like to teleport them to other coordinates if they drop to Y level 8 or lower.

Is there a lite way of doing this without have a command run on every "move" event getting each players location then getting their y position then checking if it's less than 9? cause that seems like it would be a lot of work on the server if there are many people moving around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use the `SyncRepeatingTask`. Then loop through all online players and check if their Y coordinate value is less than 9:

```
plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (Player player: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) { // Loops through all online players
            if (player.getLocation().getY() < 9) {
                // The player's Y is below 9. Do whatever you want here. For example:
                player.teleport(player.getLocation().add(0, 100, 0)); // Teleports the player 100 blocks above where they are
            }
        }
    }
}, 50L, 50L); // Run every 2.5 seconds (50 ticks)
```

Just make sure to put the above code in your `onEnable()`, or a method that's called when your plugin is enabled.

If you want to change the repeat time dynamically based on the online players, you could use:

```
public void runTeleportTask() {

    long time = Math.round(Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers().length / 10) + 10;

    /*
        Tweak the delay however you like, above we get the online players, and divide it by 10 then
        add ten. We're adding 10 because you don't want to end up with a task that runs every
        tick in this case... The fastest it would be needed would be every 10 ticks.
        So if there were 100 players online, it would get 100/10 = 10, 10+10 = 20 = 1 second,
        and if there were 250 players online, it would get 250/10 = 25, 25 + 10 = 35 = 1.75 seconds
    */

    plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                if (player.getLocation().getY() < 9) {
                    player.teleport(player.getLocation().add(0, 100, 0));
                }
            }
            runTeleportTask();
        }
    }, time);
}
```

Then all you have to do is invoke `runTeleportTask()` in your `onEnable()` method.

Comment: xD You always seem to be the one helping me out and I really appreciate it! :) Will this be at all heavy on the server if there's ~250 users online at once?

Comment: @TonyBilby Your welcome :) It shouldn't be, but If you start to run into problems then you could just increase the repeat delay to something like `100`.

Comment: Yep works great, I don't know why coping the code you wrote exactly seemed to cause an issue within eclipse around where "Runnable()" is but I used another Runnable I had and copied the for(Player p" and it works very well. Is there a way to dynamically adjust the time between checks? so if there's more than 10 player maybe go to 2.5 more than 100 players go to 4 etc?

Comment: @TonyBilby Just updated my answer with the dynamic time. And the reason the `Runnable()` part wasn't working was because I forgot to put `public void run()` inside of it... Whoops...

Comment: Wow!that works amazingly. small edit is `.size()` should be .length other than that it runs very smooth. Thank you :)

Comment: @TonyBilby No problem :), and whoops, Just fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way to do this without using runnables. Simply use a PlayerMoveEvent.

```
@EventHandler 
public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent event) {
    if (event.getPlayer().getLocation().getY() <= 8) {
        event.getPlayer().teleport(event.getPlayer().getLocation().add(0, 100, 0));
    }
}
```